# How to automatically log in user to their instagram account on new device if I have access_token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have build an app that an Instagram user have authorized on desktop A, and my app server have the access_token saved.

Now user opens my app on mobile phone, is there a way to prefill webview's cookies so user is in a logged in state on their instagram account on the mobile phone? so when the app opens instagram.com in a webview, the user is already in a login state?

Thanks

Comment: No, there likely is no way to do that. Their cookies will surely be tied to specific device characteristics.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about the issue more and since cookie is more powerful than a token, it's unlikely to be reconstructed in this way.